# Folder Destination - Upload Files

Tags: java, file, netbeans-7

I have a program which permits to upload a file from somewhere into another place. This another place is the path that will be on database. Where should I upload this file:

1. Into c://?
2. Into projectSomething/ (I´m working with glassfish and in this folder it saves on C:\Users\Alvaro\Documents\glassfish-4.0\glassfish\domains\domain1\config)
3. Into projectSomething/src/

Comment: What have you tried? Also, if the file is ending up in a database, why not just use a JDBC clob?

Comment: Please add further details of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have 2 different applications. In the first one i´m configuring a web application where a person could upload a pdf file, in order to submit his registation. On the other application, I´m configuring a back admin office where admin could upload this file, inserted on database by the person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers to such questions are always (at least partially) opinion based which is *bad* on SO. But I'll try to give you what is considered as good practice.

As you speak of glassfish, I suppose it is a web application. For evident security reasons, you should never allow uploaded files where you could have any of your application files. You should also think that some servlet containers or Java EE servlet  can display an application without exploding the war. It is clear that in such cases, you won't be able to write anything under your project root!

So where can you put it? IMHO, the best is to see that as a deployment detail and configure it in a property file, a java system property or in a environment variable **and clearly identify that in your documentation**. That way it is no longer your problem as a programmer. You will be able to deploy it under windows or linux (where C:/ does not exists) under a special directory under your project root if it is guaranteed that the war will be exploded and the application will have appropriate permissions on **that** directory.